# Interlocked functions c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-memory, interlocked

I am developing a system that uses shared memory and interlocked functions.

Let's assume i have `volatile unsigned int n, a, b`. I want to do the following pseudocode atomicly:

```
if (a <= n && n < b)
{
    n++;
}
else
{
    //Do nothing
}
```

How would I do that? Can you use multiple Interlocked functions together?

Comment: Here is some good reading to get you started: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/15/229915.aspx

Comment: Take everything you think you know about `volatile`, with respect to multithreading, and throw it away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a lock or a CAS type operation. No amount of `volatile` is going to help here.  Neither will a true atomic data type.

Comment: CAS is very well-suited for this type of operation.  Good call.  Here are [some examples](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/15/229915.aspx).

Comment: @Ben - Interesting that we both posted a link to The Old New Thing.

Comment: @vcs @ben just mentioning raymond is usually worth a couple of upvotes

Answer (score 2):

Synchronization primitives (such as semaphores, mutexes, etc.) are provided by OS-specific libraries, and not in the language itself.  C/C++ have no intrinsic "synchronized" keyword.

If you're programming on Linux, look at Posix threads or the Boost library:

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html

If you're programming on native Windows Win32 (Win98 or higher), you can use APIs like EnterCriticalSection() and InterlockedAdd(), among others:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686353%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

If you're programming Windows with .Net, however, you're back to synchronization primitives being part of the standard .Net libraries:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx

'Hope that helps .. PSM